# Чи має запозичений термін “дедлайн” синоніми українського походження?

Tags: from-english, терміни, синоніми

Щаслива людина той працівник, який не знає що таке "дедлайн".

> Ефективна робота над проектом означає відсутність режиму авралу. Якщо в роботі постійно наступає крайній термін, говорять про "deadline" – "лінії смерті", спішний штурм поставленного завдання в останній момент.
>   Якщо настав "дедлайн" – що це означає для працівника? Російське (запозичене з англійської) слово "дедлайн" значить "мертва лінія". Мертва лінія в проекті – це термін, дата, після якої з’являється ризик втратити роботу або грошей. Найнеприємніше наслідок досягнення "deadline" – неможливість отримати оплату за час, витрачений на завдання, тому планування робочого часу має вестися ефективно – грамотний менеджмент часу і зусиль означає меншу ймовірність наближення до фатальної межі.
>   Значення слова дедлайн в англійській пояснює всю суть явища – після настання такого моменту робота над документом або товаром стає безглуздою або менш вигідною. Поняття фатальної риси психологічно впливає на працівника, змушуючи його виконувати і завершувати завдання до настання часу здачі. Кінцевий результат погіршується з-за стресу перед самим кінцем строку, але деяких виконавців такий стрес навпаки стимулює і додає сил. Один і той же короткий термін вживається для позначення ситуації безвиході і сильної мотивації стресом.

[Джерело - RADKA.in.UA](http://radka.in.ua/poradi/dedlain-sho-ce-znachit-y-proektnii-r.html)

Вікіпедія [тлумачить](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD), що:

> **Дедлайн** (від англ. deadline) — англіцизм, який має таке ж значення, як і українське слово *реченець*: крайній термін (дата або/чи час), до якого має бути виконано певне завдання.

На Словотворі [надають](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/dedlain) досить велику кількість замінників:
*речене́ць, крайняк, кінцевий термін, строк, часоріз, крайня межа, невстигайко, кінцестрок, кончина, межничка, краймежа, межень, межа, термін, зрѡк, дохла ламка, крайчас, зрік, край-дата, кінтер, кінцевий термін, часомрець, часздох, краєць, одірець, речинець, ви́слід, закінчення, кінечник, остаточна дата, мертва лінія, крайня риса.*

Який з термінів є найближче лінгвістично та змістовно підходящим, відповідно до наведеного значення слова? Чи можна його буде вживати як синонім при офіційному написанні?

Answer (score 5):

З СУМ-20

> **[ДЕДЛА́ЙН](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=190702&page=720)** у, ч. Кінцевий термін, до якого має бути виконане певне завдання. *З огляду на дедлайн і власну нерішучість я зупинився
> на половинчастому варіанті* (Ю. Іздрик); *Організатори конференції
> оголосили дедлайн прийняття заявок на участь у ній* (з газ.).

Оскільки в значені не вказано, що слово діалектне чи розмовне, можемо вживати в офіційному писані.

Comment: @Yola, одначе, інформація про те, що слово вже нормативне — корисна; я, наприклад, не знав, думав, це поки що лише сленг.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>Спробую полегшити справу наступним відповідачам.</sup>

Иншомовного походження

- *[кінцевий] термін* — лат. [terminus](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom5.pdf#page=554)
- *кінтер*
- *край-дата* — лат. [datum](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom2.pdf#page=13)
- *остаточна дата*
- *мертва лінія* — лат. [linea](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom3.pdf#page=263)

Нашого

- *рече<sup>и</sup>не́ць* та *[кінце][строк](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom5.pdf#page=448)*, *зрік* — сутямки і походять від [ректи](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom5.pdf#page=52)

  СУМ‑11 має [*строк*](http://sum.in.ua/s/strok) і [*реченець*](http://sum.in.ua/s/rechenecj).

  [Вікі](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD_(%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81)#%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD_%D1%87%D0%B8_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA) з джерелами на [ЦК](http://zakon4.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/435-15) і ДСТУ 1.5:2003 вказує, що *строк* є *періодом*, отже не [дуже] підходить, оскільки в означеннях *deadline*, як і *термін*, є *певним моментом*.

  Але якщо маєте на увазі *період*, то можна вжити [*граничний реченець*](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=deadline&dicts=4&highlight=on), але за [*терміном*](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=deadline&highlight=on), вочевидь, перевага. Можна *строк* залишити з старим означенням, а [*реченець*](//archive.org/stream/shtepa1977#page/n471/mode/2up) означити *терміном*, в такому разі все гаразд.
- [*закінчення*](http://sum.in.ua/s/zakinchennja) як *кінцева частина, кінець чого-небудь* — є, по-моєму, непоганим словом
- *крайчас* непогане, оскільки [*крайнебо*](http://sum.in.ua/s/krajnebo) як *лінія горизонту*

  Відси *краймежа*, *крайня риса/межа* не [дуже] підходять, оскільки повтор.
- [*меже<sup>i</sup>нь*](http://sum.in.ua/s/mezhenj) не [дуже] підходить, бо вже має власне означення „періоду“  як *період річного циклу, протягом якого спостерігається низький рівень води в річці, озері, ставку*
- [*межа*](http://sum.in.ua/s/mezha) — зручне і доволї багатозначне, як і [*line*](//dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/line), непогано заходить також [вираз](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=50422"%D0%A1%D0%A3%D0%9C%E2%80%9120"):

  - *остання межа* — кінець, край, крах і т. ін. чого-небудь
  - *на [тій] останній межі* — перед смертю — ось і звʼязок з *dead*

Залишилося

> крайняк, часоріз, невстигайко, кончина, межничка, дохла ламка, часомрець, часздох, краєць, одірець, ви́слід, кінечник

Answer (score 1):

Українська [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD) пропонує варіант [реченець](http://sum.in.ua/s/rechenecj) і дає посилання на СУМ.

Цікавим варіантом мені здається "край-дата", який можна побачити на [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/dedlain) (там же знову можна зустріти слово "реченець").

Про "реченець" як найкращий відповідник до слова "дедлайн" можна також прочитати і в статті "[Філологи кажуть, що українську мову ми засмічуємо іноземними словами](https://expres.online/archive/news/2017/03/31/235407-filology-kazhut-ukrayinsku-movu-my-zasmichuyemo-inozemnymy-slovamy)", і в статті "[Дедлайнувато](http://m.tyzhden.ua/column/192541)".